# choose checkbox in QListWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have this code with pyqt5:

```
elif (content1 == "next"):
        todos = ["one" , "two" , "three" , "four", "five"]
        self.todo_listWidget.show()
        for todo in todos:
            item = QListWidgetItem(todo)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked) 
 
            self.todo_listWidget.addItem(item)
```

And I want if i chose one item make something
like if item (x) is checked then do something

how can i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Connect the `itemChanged` signal of `self.todo_listWidget` with a function that takes the item as its argument.

> This signal is emitted whenever the data of item has changed.

In the function, you can check the resp. item's `checkState` and proceed accordingly.

An alternative is `itemActivated`. Which one works better for you depends on if you want to react to all (also programmatical) changes of the check state or only to user interaction.

> This signal is emitted when the item is activated. The item is activated when the user clicks or double clicks on it, depending on the system configuration. It is also activated when the user presses the activation key (on Windows and X11 this is the Return key, on Mac OS X it is Command+O).